# How to disable DEP on OSX Lion

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-xe2, dep

A dylib I created crashes under Lion, but works just fine under Snow Leopard. This seems to be caused by a compiler bug (Delphi XE2, Upd.4) which results in code ending up in a data section.

When the dylib is loaded, there's a SIGBUS with KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at an address within a RODATA section.

Since I need to get this working under Lion ASAP, is there a way to disable DEP under Lion?

Comment: At least report it at http://qc.embarcadero.com (If you need help with a reproducible case, let me know) to get it fixed in the next update.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers I'm already in contact with support, there's at least one RAID entry and AFAIK R&D is aware of the problem.

Comment: thanks; please mention that QC entry number (preferably as a link) in your question.